# How to restart bokeh server with Gulp on file changes?

Tags: python, gulp, bokeh, livereload

Is it possible to reload bokeh server with gulp on any file changes?
Is there something like livereload for Bokeh?

For example, I change anything on frontend side. Gulp automatically watches for changes and use live reload, but page is not reloaded, I need to reload it manually or restart the server 'bokeh serve myapp'.
Is it possible to watch for changes and reload the server?